# How to replace copyWith so as not to copy, but to create a new state?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a bloc which is responsible for switching indexes in the Navogation Bottom Bar.It is implemented in such a way that it copies the old state and changes it. I need to replace copyWith and make it not copy but create a new state. How can this be implemented and rewritten given bloc?

```js
class BottomNavyBloc extends Bloc<BottomNavyEvent, BottomNavyState> {
  BottomNavyBloc() : super(const BottomNavyState()) {
    on<ChangePageEvent>(
          (event, emit) => emit(
        state.copyWith(index: event.index),
      ),
    );
  }
}

abstract class BottomNavyEvent extends Equatable {
  const BottomNavyEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class ChangePageEvent extends BottomNavyEvent {
  final int index;

  const ChangePageEvent({
    required this.index,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [index];
}
```

My state:

```js
class BottomNavyState extends Equatable {
  const BottomNavyState({
    this.index = 0,
  });

  final int index;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [index];
}

class ChangePageState extends BottomNavyState {

}
```

Comment: As there is only one variable `index`, the state change with `copyWith` works almost similar to using new Event. What is the problem with the current code?

Comment: I just need to remake it under these conditions. To replace copyWith. I want to know how it's done

Comment: I have answered it assuming that there is a state with only one variable, you could use the similar method to emit new states instead of copying from previous state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use

```dart
emit(state.copyWith(index: event.index))
```

to say that we are copying all the elements from the previous state by changing `index`.

Your state `BottomNavyState` has only one variable as of now. So, the above `copyWith` acts similar to using emitting new state.

We should not try to change or override the method `copyWith` because it beats the method's actual purpose.

Instead, you could use

```dart
emit(BottomNavyState(index: event.index))
```

to use a new state constructor instead of copying from previous state.

Comment: I forgot to add a file with my state. Now I have added. Tell me please, what should I write in my ChangePageState class?

Comment: You already have `BottomNavyState`. So, you can emit the same and don't need `ChangePageState`. I just assumed it was that. So, just replace `ChangePageState` with `BottomNavyState`, it will work fine. (I will also edit the answer). You can just remove `ChangePageState` class, as we won't be needing it.